# Django Rest Framework: Custom url pattern for Detail model-viewset with datetime lookup field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet defined with lookup field as `timestamp` (a datetime field) instead of default `pk` field

Here is my code:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ACFCrowdData

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    lookup_field = 'timestamp'
```

`timestamp` field is of type `models.DatetimeField`.

Now I want to access the detail viewset of my model by specifying datetime lookup pattern as `YYYYMMDDHHMISS`in the url. Instead it only accepts the default format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS`

I want to accomplish this. I want my detail viewset to be routed to `http://example.com/mymodel/YYYYMMDDHHMISS`

Any help or hint would be nice

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom `retrieve` method and use your own timestamp parser. Something like this might do the trick. I haven't tried this specific code out, but the principle should work.

```
from datetime import datetime

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    ...

    def retrieve(self, request, timestamp=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        try:
             parsedtime = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        except ValueError:
             # incorrect timestamp  
             ...
        record = get_object_or_404(queryset, timestamp=parsedtime)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(record)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks. btw, I suppose datetime stripping is of the format `datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')` rather than `datetime.strptime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', timestamp)`

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer with the proper order of arguments for strptime.